# Groupings over non-atomic elements

Tags: expression-manipulation

I use groupings as below:

```
Join[
  Groupings[IntegerPartitions[3], {A -> {2, Orderless}, B -> {2, Orderless}}], 
  {x}]
```

Which generates:

> ```
> {A[2, 1], B[2, 1], A[A[1, 1], 1], A[B[1, 1], 1], B[A[1, 1], 1], B[B[1, 1], 1], 3}
> ```

How can `A` be restricted so `A` is not applied to arguments that are *both* atomic? That is. I want the output to be:

> ```
> {B[2, 1], A[B[1, 1], 1], B[B[1, 1], 1], 3}
> ```

Of course, I can remove the results in which `A` is applied to two atoms (i.e. two positive integers) after generating the list:

```
{A[2, 1], B[2, 1], A[A[1, 1], 1], A[B[1, 1], 1], B[A[1, 1], 1], B[B[1, 1], 1], 3}
```

Is it possible to do prevent generating the cases where `A` applies to two atoms (integers in this case) by adapting the given code:

```
Join[
  Groupings[IntegerPartitions[3], {A -> {2, Orderless}, B -> {2, Orderless}}], 
  {x}]
```

For example, by adding a condition

```
/, ! AtomQ[x] && !AtomQ[y]
```

for an application `A[x,y]`?

Comment: What should happen to `B[A[1,1],1]`?

Comment: It should not be added (it is not included in the intended result displayed). It contains A[1,1] which is not allowed since A is applied to two atoms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a variation of kglr's answer that doesn't modify `A` or `B`. First define a helper function `h`:

```
h[A[___?AtomQ] | A[_]] := Sequence[]
h[B[_] | B[]] := Sequence[]
h[a_] := a
```

Then use the helper function in your [`Groupings`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Groupings) call:

```
Groupings[IntegerPartitions[3], {h @* A -> {2, Orderless}, h @* B -> {2, Orderless}}]
```

> {B[2, 1], A[B[1, 1], 1], B[B[1, 1], 1]}

Comment: Thanks Carl. This is what I got now and it seems to work fine:                                               Block[{a, b}, a = A; b = B; h[a[__?AtomQ]] := Sequence[];
 h[b[_]] := Sequence[];
 h[c_] := c; 
 Groupings[
  IntegerPartitions[3], {h@*A -> {2, Orderless}, 
   h@*B -> {2, Orderless}}]]
Result: {B[2, 1], A[B[1, 1], 1], B[B[1, 1], 1]}

Comment: Unfortunately this still does not work on size 4:   Groupings[IntegerPartitions[4], {h @* A -> {2, Orderless}, h @* B -> {2, Orderless}}]  Produces: {B[3, 1], B[2, 2], A[B[2, 1], 1], B[B[2, 1], 1], A[], 
 A[A[B[1, 1], 1], 1], A[B[1, 1]], A[B[1, 1]], B[], 
 A[B[B[1, 1], 1], 1], A[B[1, 1], B[1, 1]], B[A[B[1, 1], 1], 1], 
 B[B[B[1, 1], 1], 1], B[B[1, 1], B[1, 1]]} This contains A[] and also A[B[1, 1]], the latter of which should not be included as A is a binary operation

Comment: @Mike See update

Comment: Thanks Carl! Much appreciated. I need to read up on the operations you used...

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[a, b]
a = A;
b = B;
a[___?AtomQ] := Sequence[]
b[_] := Sequence[]

Groupings[IntegerPartitions[3], {a -> {2, Orderless}, b -> {2, Orderless}}]
```

> {B[2, 1], A[B[1, 1], 1], B[B[1, 1], 1]}

Comment: I can't use ClearAll, as A and B have other values attached. But removing ClearAll does not cause an issue. There is another problem though: Is it possible to protect (i.e. restrict use locally) the commands:           A[_?AtomQ,___?AtomQ]:=Sequence[]
B[_]:=Sequence[]       similar to local variables? I do not wish these commands to affect A and B outside the context I am using the above commands in.

Comment: @Mike, does `Block[{a,b}, a=A;b=B;a[_?AtomQ,__?AtomQ]:= ...]` work?

Comment: Almost, the code:                                                                                                                                                                                       Block[{a, b}, a = A; b = B; a[_?AtomQ, __?AtomQ] :=
   Sequence[];
 B[_] := Sequence[];
 Groupings[
  IntegerPartitions[3], {A -> {2, Orderless}, B -> {2, Orderless}}]] produces: {B[2, 1], A[1], A[B[1, 1], 1], B[B[1, 1], 1]} which includes A[1]. It should not as A is an operation on two arguments.

Comment: Thanks kgl, went with Carl's solution in the end, but this got it going